# How to disable scroll outside of NumberPicker element in Android

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I have a NumberPicker element close to the bottom of the Activity. When the user scrolls down, the 'back' button gets clicked. I would like to disable scroll outside of the NumberPicker area.

**Number picker shown just above back button**
[image]

There doesn't seem to be an explicit option for doing this.

Here is the xml which is inside a fragment:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/string1_id" />

            <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/number_picker_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"></NumberPicker>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I expect that when the finger scrolls past the NumberPicker area, the NumberPicker stops scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this block of code after android **LOLLIPOP** version

```
number_pick_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        number_pick.stopNestedScroll();
    }

  }
});
```